# Highlight paths matching patterns (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, mat-table

I have a list of paths, which can contain wildcards. What would be the best approach for filtering/highlighting paths matching paths containing wildcards? So that the path '/server/test/block' would be marked when you also have the path '/server/*' f.ex. So far I've tried nesting .filter with .contains, and checking if the array is larger than 1. However, that would only give exact matches, and I did not find a good way to add the same class to those that matched eachother.

To run that function, I tested the [innerHTML]-selector on my mat-cell, but the function was run **many** times. I also tested using the [class.someName]-selector on a span inside the mat-cell, but this would also call the function many, many times. Any pointers on which direction I should be looking would be appreciated.

The data is shown using a material table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a boolean to the dataset, 'matchesPattern'. I found a [npm module named minimatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimatch) which gives a boolean depending on pattern match or not.

```
import minimatch from 'minimatch';

markMatchingPaths() {
  this.dataSource.data.map(p => p.matchesPattern = false);
  const wildcards = this.currentDataSource.data.filter(w => w.path.includes('*'));

  wildcards.forEach(w => {
    this.dataSource.data.forEach(p => {
      const res = minimatch(p.path, w.path);
      if (res) {
        p.matchesPattern = true;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I used said boolean with [class.someName] to add a class to the span surround the paths. They are now highlighted in a different color.